# Using aggregate on another aggregate function - MAX() on an aggregate

Tags: sql, t-sql, partitioning

I've a tournament bracket consisting of 2 Groups (Group A and Group B).
I already have a query where I retreive some information such as the average rating, amount of teams etc.

To the **problem**: I don't want to allow 2 teams of the same group having the same color. I want a column **representing** the `MAX()` of *ColorInterference* **without** having to make a subselect.

Is this possible or am I forced to make a `SELECT MAX(ColorInterference)` over the query result?

| Group | Team | Color | Rating | TeamsCount | AverageRating | AverageRatingGroup | ColorInterference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Helos | Green | 1452 | 8 | 1518 | 1544 | 0 |
| A | Pelicans | Purple | 1687 | 8 | 1518 | 1544 | 0 |
| A | Epic Square Dance | Red | 1498 | 8 | 1518 | 1544 | 0 |
| A | Narnia Ninjas | Yellow | 1542 | 8 | 1518 | 1544 | 0 |
| B | O.T. | Blue | 1502 | 8 | 1518 | 1492 | 0 |
| B | Helos | **Green** | 1452 | 8 | 1518 | 1492 | 1 |
| B | Treasure Goggles | **Green** | 1485 | 8 | 1518 | 1492 | 1 |
| B | Red Off | Yellow | 1530 | 8 | 1518 | 1492 | 0 |

```
DECLARE @Bracket_Groups Table ([Group] nvarchar(10), Team nvarchar(50), Color nvarchar(50), Rating int)
INSERT INTO @Bracket_Groups(Team, [Group], Color, Rating)
SELECT        'Narnia Ninjas', 'A', 'Yellow' , 1542
UNION SELECT  'Helos', 'A', 'Green', 1452
UNION SELECT  'Pelicans', 'A', 'Purple', 1687
UNION SELECT  'Epic Square Dance', 'A', 'Red', 1498
UNION SELECT  'O.T.', 'B', 'Blue', 1502
UNION SELECT  'Red Off', 'B', 'Yellow', 1530
UNION SELECT  'Helos', 'B', 'Green', 1452
UNION SELECT  'Treasure Goggles', 'B', 'Green', 1485

SELECT 
    [Group]
  , Team
  , Color
  , Rating
  , COUNT(*)  OVER()                                          as TeamsCount
  , AVG(Rating) OVER ()                                       as AverageRating
  , AVG(Rating) OVER (Partition By [Group])                   as Group_AverageRating
  , SIGN(COUNT(Color) OVER (partition By [Group], Color) - 1) as ColorInterference
FROM @Bracket_Groups
Order by [Group]
```

Comment: Why not assign a colour to a specific `ROW_NUMBER`? For example, `1` is green, `2` is blue, `3` is red, etc, etc.

Comment: In my real case I cannot decide which colors the teams have myself. In the real case it's not even a tornament bracket, teams nor colors. I just thought it was easier to illustrate this way :)

Comment: I'm confused: you seem to be talking about two different problems. *"To the problem: I don't want to allow 2 teams of the same group having the same color. I want a column representing the MAX() of ColorInterference without having to make a subselect."* For the first, perhaps you need a unique/primary key over `(Group, Team, Color)`. For the second problem, if you want an aggregate of an aggregate, you must use a subselect/derived table. But it's unclear what your expected results are, perhaps there is another way of calculating it.

Comment: Note that `COUNT(Color)` is always going to be the same as `COUNT(*)` if `Color` is not nullable

Comment: Hi @Charlieface ,
This query is just used for a view so I can't make use of any keys.  
Basically I want a column as TeamsCount that shows the total `COUNT()` (not just the rows count), but I want a `MAX()` on column *ColorInterference*. 

So if there's just one row that has the value 1 in *ColorInterference*, I'd want my new column to show 1 in All rows.

preferably without having to make a subselect :)

Comment: So you don't want to change the table, you just want to query the windowed counts? And this MaxCount you want partitioned how? It sounds like you should just remove `[Group]` from the partitioning clause